# what is the best approximation of minimum value of $e^{-x}\sin(100x)$

Tags: functions, maxima-minima

> Q. What is the best approximation of the minimum value attained by $e^{-x}\sin(100x)\ \ \quad$ such that $ x\ge 0$

My trial: 
$$f(x)=e^{-x}\sin(100x)$$
$$f'(x)=100e^{-x}\cos(100x)-e^{-x}\sin(100x)$$
$$f''(x)=-9999e^{-x}\sin(100x)-200e^{-x}\cos(100x)$$
for minima, 
$$f'(x)=0\implies100e^{-x}\cos(100x)-e^{-x}\sin(100x)=0$$
$$\tan(100x)=100\quad \because e^{-x}\ne0 $$
$$100x=k\pi+\tan^{-1}(100)=k\pi+1.56$$
$$x=\ldots-0.0158, 0, 0.0156, 0.04702, \dots\quad (\text{all values in radian})$$
here k is any integer. From graph there exist a number of minima of function $e^{-x}\sin(100x)$ but i don't know which values of k or $x\ge0$ should be taken to find the best approximation of minimum value. Somebody please help  me solve it.
My book suggests that **answer must lie in the range $-1$ to $-0.94$**

thanks

Comment: You forgot to divide by 100.

Comment: thank you i fixed the error please help me solve it

Comment: If you graph the function, it looks pretty much like a decaying sine wave with envelope $- e^{-x} \le y \le e^{-x}$.  So, a rough approximation would be that the minimum happens close to the first minimum of $\sin (100 x)$, which is when $100 x = \frac{3\pi}{2}$, and the minimum value is about $-e^{-3\pi / 200}$.